# what is different between office 365 SharePoint and SharePoint on-premise? (using API)

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-on-prem, api, sdk

I want to develop application that can access SharePoint on-premise server and download files from that server.

I already developed JAVA application using REST API of Office 365 SharePoint.

so what is different when developing application between office 365 SharePoint and  on-premise server?

I want to know environment setting / SDK download / supported programming language(C#...etc)

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that on premise supports server deployments. This enables access to server side API's.

Client side API provides very less functionality compared to Server side.

For development you should use Visual Studio. I am not sure what application you created in JAVA. So can't comment much on this topic.

Since you are already aware of the REST end points you can use AJAX to call those.

Comment: So you mean if I want to develop application that can access files and download, I should server side API? Is It right?

Comment: You can choose based on the requirements. I was stating the main advantage of on premises.

Comment: My question is focused on difference of API. That's why I commented JAVA application using Office 365 Sharepoint REST API. But I have never developed application using Sharepoint SDK, so I don't know how to start.